# Python NLP : How to print a formatted list of words from a textblob.? (output attached as an image)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am reading classics to text blob for NLTK bases sentimental analysis and i would like to print formatted wordlists from a text blob. I figured a solution after some search  and the code and results are below with a sample text. But is there a more elegant and generic solution ?

Expected functionality  is print_words function should take a textbob and print a specified number of comma separated, numbered words in a line.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import nltk
# nltk.download('punkt')
# nltk.download('brown')
# nltk.download('stopwords')

text="""Two households, both alike in dignity,In fair Verona, where we lay our scene,From ancient grudge break to new mutiny,' 
'Where civil blood makes civil hands unclean.From forth the fatal loins of these two foes A pair of star-cross’d lovers take their life;'
'Whose misadventur’d piteous overthrows"""
blobText =TextBlob(text)

test_1=""
for i in range(0, len(blobText.words)):
 test_1+= (str(i)+". "+ blobText.words[i]+","+"_")

test_2=list(test_1.split("_")) 

def print_words(num_words):
   print(*test_2[num_words:num_words+10])


for i in range(0, len(blobText.words),10):
  print_words(i)

print("\n", "Count of words =", len(blobText.words))
```

output: image attached[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD7aq.png)

Comment: hi, would you like a specific formatting

Comment: Yes. Just a comma separated, numbered (word count) words  with a specified number of words in a line.  I attached an image -not sure you can see it .

Comment: 0. Two, 1. households, 2. both, 3. alike, 4. in, 5. dignity, 6. In, 7. fair, 8. Verona, 9. where,
10. we, 11. lay, 12. our, 13. scene, 14. From, 15. ancient, 16. grudge, 17. break, 18. to, 19. new,
20. mutiny, 21. 'Where, 22. civil, 23. blood, 24. makes, 25. civil, 26. hands, 27. unclean.From, 28. forth, 29. the,
30. fatal, 31. loins, 32. of, 33. these, 34. two, 35. foes, 36. A, 37. pair, 38. of, 39. star-cross,
40. ’, 41. d, 42. lovers, 43. take, 44. their, 45. life, 46. 'Whose, 47. misadventur, 48. ’, 49. d,
50. piteous, 51. overthrows, 

 Count of words = 52